# How to get indexOf multiple delimiters?

Tags: java, regex, string, indexof

I am looking for an elegant way to find the first appearance of one of a set of delimiters.

For example, let's assume my delimiter set is composed of `{";",")","/"}`.

If my String is
`"aaa/bbb;ccc)"`
I would like to get the result 3 (the index of the `"/"`, since it is the first to appear).

If my String is
`"aa;bbbb/"`
I would like to get the result 2 (the index of the `";"`, since it is the first to appear).

and so on.

If the String does not contain any delimiter, I would like to return `-1`.

I know I can do it by first finding the index of each delimiter, then calculating the minimum of the indices, disregarding the `-1`'s. This code becomes very cumbersome. I am looking for a shorter and more generic way.

Comment: Instead of trying to find each delimiter one by one, it would be more efficient to iterate over the characters of the string, and test if each char is one of the delimiter. Or you could use a regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Through regex , it woud be done like this,

```
String s =  "aa;bbbb/";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[;/)]").matcher(s);   // [;/)] would match a forward slash or semicolon or closing bracket.
if(m.find())                                       // if there is a match found, note that it would find only the first match because we used `if` condition not `while` loop.
{
    System.out.println(m.start());                 // print the index where the match starts.

}
else
{
    System.out.println("-1");                      // else  print -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search in list of delimiter each character from the input string.  If found then print the index. 
You can also use Set to store delimiters

Answer (score 0):

Below program will gives the result. this is done using RegEx.

```
  import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FindIndexUsingRegex {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    findMatches("aaa/bbb;ccc\\)",";|,|\\)|/");
}

public static void findMatches(String source, String regex) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.print("First index: " + matcher.start()+"\n");
        System.out.print("Last index: " + matcher.end()+"\n");
        System.out.println("Delimiter: " + matcher.group()+"\n");
        break;
    }
}

}
```

Output:

```
   First index: 3
Last index: 4
Delimiter: /
```